# Query for spatial intersection (point - polygons in column) using postgreSQL and PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to figure out how to create a query, which asks for points within a polygon. 
My setup is a postgreSQL 9.5 instance with a installed PostGIS 2.2.2 extension.
Theoretically this might not be really difficult as it is shown in the [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html), but I am not able to get any result.

I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE app_db.testTable
(
  message_text text,
  message_picture text,
  message_date timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  message_id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  message_position app_db.geometry,
  message_radius integer,
  message_circle app_db.geometry,
  message_userid uuid,
  CONSTRAINT messages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (message_id)
)
```

I've enabled PostGIS with the following command for my schemata:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA app_db;
```

And I've put some example datasets in the above mentioned table. 
So far so good.

Not I'm trying to create a query, which should ask for all data, where the defined point intersects one of the geometries stored in my table column **app_db -> message.circle**:
As far as I've understood ST_Intersects needs two geometries as parameters, but how do I perform a query in regard to a complete column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that normally folks install `postgis` into `public` and/or have the installed schema on the `search_path` so you don't need to provide full paths like `app_db.ST_Intersects`. For the examples below, I'm assuming `SET search_path TO app_db;` to make it simpler.

To select all the points in `message_position` from a single polygon in `message_circle`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM testTable p
JOIN testTable c ON c.message_id='the id of the circle'
    AND p.message_id <> c.message_id
    AND ST_Intersects(p.message_position, c.message_circle);
```

I'm not sure how `message_circle` was made, but if it was created from `message_position` and `message_radius`, then a better way is to use [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), which uses a distance threshold, rather than a more expensive and imperfect geometry analysis.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM testTable p
JOIN testTable c ON c.message_id='the id of the circle'
    AND p.message_id <> c.message_id
    AND ST_DWithin(p.message_position, c.message_position, c.message_radius);
```

It can be sped up by creating a GiST spatial index on `message_position`.

Comment: Thanks! This wa exactly what I was looking for! Especially the hint relating to the performance is quite helpful :)